# quicksearch dissapear after 2/3 letters

Tags: php, html

i have that table and a div with a quicksearch and after i write 2 or 3 letters he show results, but then the div search dissapear after show the results and if i want to write something new, i have to refresh the page

thats the div

```
<table id="tabela" class="table admin">
          <tr class="outro">
            <th width="15%">
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.3.1/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
              <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                <input name="consulta" id="txt_consulta" placeholder="Procurar..." type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </th>
            <th width="10%"></th>
            <th width="30%"></th>
            <th width="15%">
              <a href="utilizadores/novoutilizador" class="link"><img src="../assets/img/add.PNG" class="icone" />Adicionar utilizador</a>
              </a>
            </th>
          </tr>


          <tr class="tabela">
            <th width="10%">
              <p>Nome</p>
            </th>
            <th width="5%"></th>
            <th width="30%">
              <p>Permissões</p>
            </th>
            <th width="10%"></th>
          </tr>
          <?php
          foreach ($utilizadores as $key => $value) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . '<p class="texto">' . $value->nome . '</p>' . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">' . '<p>Info</p>' . '</button></td>';
            echo '<td>';
            if ($value->tipo_user == "1") {
              echo '<p class="texto">' . "Administrador" . '</p>';
            } else if ($value->tipo_user == "2") {
              echo '<p class="texto">' . "Gestor" . '</p>';
            } else {
              echo '<p class="texto">' . "Utilizador" . '</p>';
            }
            '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . base_url() . 'index.php/utilizadores/delete/' . $value->id_user . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Tem a certeza que pretende apagar esse utilizador?\')" ><p class="eliminar">Eliminar</p></a></td></tr>';
          }
          ?>
        </table>
```

and thats the script

```
<script>
      $('input#txt_consulta').quicksearch('table#tabela tbody tr');
    </script>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: To few infos provided. I guess you either have a script file not included (like jquery) or your table id is different.
Also please read the guidelines for asking questions. This is no Codeigniter question.

Comment: i already put all the code and uptade the tag to html and php

Answer (score 0):

It's because your quicksearch filters all rows of your table. You can solve that by giving your dynamically added rows a class and set quicksearch upon that class.

```
echo '<tr class="filter_row"><td>' . '<p class="texto">' . $value->nome . '</p>' . '</td>';
```

and then you have to add that to the configuration script:

```
<script>
  $('input#txt_consulta').quicksearch('table#tabela tbody tr.filter_row');
</script>
```